# Group action by $\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

Let $x.z=e^{ix}z$. Show that this is a group action by $\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{C}$.

So far this is what I have got:

i) It has to satisfy $1_{\mathbb{R}}.z=z$

$1_{\mathbb{R}}=0$, so we get: $1_{\mathbb{R}}.z=e^{i*0}z=1*z=z$.

So i) is satisfied, now we need to satisfy:

ii) $x_1.(x_2.z)=(x_1x_2).z$

$x_1.(x_2.z)=x_1.e^{ix_2}z=e^{ix_1}e^{ix_2}z$

but $(x_1x_2).z=e^{ix_1x_2}z$

so ii) is not satisfied, even though it should be.

The semester is coming to a close so I might be missing something obvious here.. Any pointers?

Comment: Since you are using $0$ as the identity element your group operation in $\mathbb{R}$ is addition. So you need to check that $x_1 \cdot (x_2 \cdot z) = (x_1 + x_2) \cdot z$. You've almost done this.

Comment: The group structure on $\Bbb R$ is supposed to be the *additive* one. So $x_1.x_2$ is $x_1 + x_2$, **not** the product $x_1x_2$

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain oh god, I knew it was something obvious... Thank you, haha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to define a group action... You need to have a group. In your question, you say *Let $x$...* omitting to say of which group you're speaking.

I imagine that the group is $(\mathbb R ,+)$. In which case, you indeed have a group action as

$$x_1 \cdot(x_2 \cdot z) = e^{ix_1}(e^{ix_2}z) = e^{i(x_1+x_2)}z= (x_1+x_2)\cdot z.$$

Comment: As stated, of course I would miss something obvious like this.. Thanks a lot!